# AwsUpload/S3Client how do I refresh credentials after multi-part credentials have expired?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js-v3

I have a multi-part upload, using AWS JS SDK v3, that takes a long time. After one hour the credentials expire. I need to find a way to refresh the credentials to keep the upload going. I can ask my backend for new credentials, I just need to understand where to inject them.

The response I get is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>
        ExpiredToken
    </Code>
    <Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
    <Token-0>REDACTED</Token-0>
    <RequestId>REDACTED</RequestId>
    <HostId>REDACTED</HostId>
</Error>
```

The code I'm using looks like this:

```js
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Upload as AwsUpload, Progress } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";
import type { AwsCredentialIdentity } from "@aws-sdk/types/dist-types/identity/AwsCredentialIdentity";

// ...


const { accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken } = session.uploadCredentials;
const selectedFile: File = //...
const region: string = // ...
const key: string = // ...
const multipartUpload = new AwsUpload({
    client: new S3Client({
        maxAttempts: 10,
        region,
        credentials: async (): Promise<AwsCredentialIdentity> => {
            return {
                accessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey,
                sessionToken,
            };
        },
    }),
    params: { Bucket: session.bucket, Key: key, Body: selectedFile },
});

// Irrelevant, but for completeness:
multipartUpload.on("httpUploadProgress", handleUploadProgress);
multipartUpload.done().then(handleUploadResponse).catch(handleUploadError);
```

I can't figure out how to configure the SDK to ask me for new credentials, when necessary. Can it be done?

Comment: Can you get longer lived credentials? Where are these creds coming from? If not, how large are your files typically?

Comment: You could also play with `partSize` and `queueSize` to see if you can finish it in the one hour. `Upload` (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/lib/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts) won't be the issue here; it's the S3 client 'expiring'. The surefire way to do this would be to extend/clone/recreate the `Upload` class and add in logic to feed new creds from your backend to create a new S3 client and use that to sign the reqs post-expiry of the creds on the first client.

There may be other neater ways of doing it using cred providers but I'd have to dig really deep to give you an answer

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Unfortunately I don't control the file size. Up to 20GiB and people are using janky 4G connections. The maximum credential time from AWS is one hour, clearly stated in their docs. I'll see what I can come up with wrt extending AwsUpload.

Comment: The maximum credential lifetime is definitely not one hour for all credential types in AWS. How are you getting your access token?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary The credentials are derived from a role, and the maximum allowed by AWS is 1hr https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use.html